How can I find the time complexity of this particular code?
I have reviewed a lot of my material provided by tutors and searched google and watch videos extensively and while I have some understanding of how to determine basic time complexities, I struggle to actually verify if my answer is correct. For context I'm trying to determine the worst case time complexities of a method which I'll provide below.
What do I know already
Say for a simple for loop like the one below:
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
}


int k=0; This will be executed only once.
The time is actually calculated to k=0 and not the declaration.

k < N; This will be executed N+1 times
k++ This will be executed N times
So the number of operations required by this loop are {1+(N+1)+N} = 2N+2. (But this still may be wrong, as I am not confident about my understanding.)


OK, so these small basic calculations I think I know, but in most cases I have seen the time complexity as O(N), O(n^2), O(log n), O(n!)
So my main question is how would I determine the worst case time complexity for this code shown below?
public void Add(IMember member)
{
    // To be implemented by students
    Member amember = new Member(member.FirstName, member.LastName, member.ContactNumber, member.Pin);

    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        members[0] = amember;
        count++;
        return;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        if (members[j].FirstName == amember.FirstName && members[j].LastName == amember.LastName)
        {
            return; // this member is a duplicate so we simply ignore it and don't add it to the array of members 
        }
    }

    int i;

    for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // use the compare method to compare members 
        if (members[i].CompareTo(amember) > 0)
        {
            // if the current member should come after the new member move it up to make space
            members[i + 1] = members[i];
        }
        else
        {
            // found the position break from the loop 
            break;
        }
    }

    // insert the new member 
    members[i + 1] = amember;
    count++;
}

And this is the CompareTo method code which affects a lot the output in most cases:
public int CompareTo(IMember member)
{
    // concatenate the members first and lastname into a full name
    string fullnamethis = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    string fullnameother = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName;

    // considering the fullname ensures that in cases where someone has the same first name but a different last name they are still added to the members array
    // instead of being considered duplicates
    return fullnamethis.CompareTo(fullnameother);
}

Context
For context this is algorithm which is used to add a new member to a member collection object which in this case is an array. The aim of this method is to add new members to collection and keep the collection sorted in alphabetical order by first and last name. Now whilst this is successful in doing we lose marks for having developed an inefficient algorithm which would classes as something operating at O(n^2) time complexity in the worst case. So my aim is to modify this method if needed to get the worst case time complexity to something more like O(n) or even O(n log n) if possible.
But the main issue I remain to have is determining if its actually needed to be modified as I believe I may have a time complexity of O(n^2) as while it doesn't explicitly use a nested for loop. The use of the CompareTo operation means that each each member is visited twice (from what I can tell I may be wrong in my thinking) which I believe would make the method have a worst case time complexity of O(n^2).
If someone is able to provide some insight on if my thinking is correct or not, and if I am correct potentially provide some tips on how I may be able to refactor the code to achieve the desired time complexity.

Since you are maintaining a sorted collection, you should exploit that when trying to locate a matching item or where this new item should be inserted, which can be done at the same time. Though if you are moving elements to make space, the worst case performance will always be O(n) as you might have to copy every element.

Some optimizations include maintaining an additional HashSet for storing the members. Search, insert, delete operations for hashSet are O(1) operations. If that's not feasible, use Binary Search to search for duplicates or finding the right place since it's already a sorted collection.

Firstly, I think that n here refers to the number of members.
For this Add method, its time complexity is O(n), because in the worst-case, when you add a new member, you need to compare it with each already added member. As more members are added, the number of comparisons will also increase proportionally.
But if they are considering the time complexity of adding a total of n members, then it is O(n^2)

No your first assumption was correct I'm only ever adding a single member to the collection. Which itself could have a total of n members

The complexity is not only determined by  (the number of members), but also by the sizes of the member's names.
One execution of compareTo will create two new strings which each are the concatenation of a member's first and last name. This operation has a time complexity of O(), where  is the total number of characters in the first and last name.
As compareTo is called on every member, combined with the new member, the total complexity is O() where  is the maximum (or average) size of a member's first or last name.
Even without compareTo, we would still have this time complexity of O(), because the other loop that looks for equality compares all first and last names with the new first and last name. In the worst case all names are almost the same, and only differ in their final letter, which means that all letters are compared, giving rise to O() time complexity.


O(1) Constant
O(n) Linear
O(n^2) Quadratic

This seems to be O(n) as there are 2 loops that grow with the input value which is a linear time complexity. (2N equals N in Big O, but in relative terms will take longer than N.)

Let's take an example, I need to add 'Jacob G.' as a new member in my already existing collection of 20 members. This name is not a duplicate.

Checking if collection is empty - This is constant time operation, since we just check if the array is empty and insert the first member.Our array contains 20 members, so this condition is false. TC -> O(1)

In the first loop, we check for duplicates. The loop will run n times, since we don't have a duplicate, where n is the number of members.


Suppose we are comparing Vedita Kamat with Jacob G,the == operator will start comparing from the leftmost character and return false when it finds a mismatch. In this case, the first letter (V & J) itself is a mismatch, so O(1) operation.
Now if we were comparing Jacob G with Jacob H. This operation is O(7) because it will compare the first 6 characters and mismatch at the 7th one.
The comparison of FirstName and LastName can be considered a constant operation if n >>> MIN(len(FirstName) + len(LastName))

The last loop will attempt to find the correct position of the new member.This loop can run at max n times, where n is the total number of members in our collection.
The compareTo function here does the following
A. It concatenates FirstName & LastName for each member along with new member.
Each of this concatenation will take O(len(FirstName) + len(LastName)) time.
Example - Vedita Kamat & Jacob G will take O(12) & O(7) time.
B. Now it compares the two names. Comparison will again take min(O(len(FirstName)+len(LastName)) time as discussed with the == case. Let's say on average, names differ at 4th index, so O(4)

If you notice, the total time complexity here is O(12+7+4) = O(23). Considering average value of O(23) for each CompareTo method for n members,
Total time complexity for this part is O(23*n). Since our n itself is 20, this is actually kind of O(n**2).
So to answer your question, for small collection size, like 20,CompareTo operation will likely contribute significantly to the time complexity and the length of FirstName, LastName will matter.
As n grows, the contribution will not matter much and it can be considered as O(1) operation.
In Big O, we usually consider large input sizes, so overall time complexity should be O(n), where n is the total members in the collection.
